# Problems with a question with some answers for iPhone 3G and then an edit to iPhone 3GS

Tags: discussion, editing

We have a question that I've closed to see if it can be salvaged:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65952/how-to-upgrade-iphone-3gs-to-ios-5-now-that-ios-6-is-out

It started out as can I upgrade an iPhone 3G to iOS 6 - where the answer is basically - NO.

Then it got edited to iPhone 3GS where the answer is YES - but now many of the comments and answers make no sense.

If I revert the edits, we need to delete the answers targeting 3GS and vice versa. Can someone propose a good solution to this other than closure?

Comment: closure AND deletion? :-)

Answer (score 2):

When did the edit to 3GS occur - Sathya's edit is not marked up as changed and the original is 3G - seems like a error in the revision history.

Thus the OP did not make this edit and given that they accepted the answer re 3G saying that upgrade not possible, I think the correct solution is to remove all 3GS references